# sh: sqlldr: command not found php passthru(); but PATH in sysconfig/httpd/ seems to be ok

Tags: php, apache, path, passthru

### php

```
passthru( 'echo $PATH >>/tmp/sqlldrproblem 2>&1' );
passthru( "sqlldr USERID=scott/tiger@dbhost control=/tmp/test.ctl log=/tmp/test.log >>/tmp/sqlldrproblem 2>&1" );
```

### Oracle Linux7.1

```
# cat /tmp/sqlldrproblem

$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
/opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1
sh: sqlldr: command not found

# which sqlldr
/opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/bin/sqlldr

# cat /etc/sysconfig/httpd
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1
export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

--

So,PATH setting seems to be correct. But the error occured.Why?

Comment: I missed one command. correctly ,on [php] side ,this is it :
passthru( 'echo $PATH >>/tmp/zipproblem 2>&1' );
passthru( 'echo $ORACLE_HOME>>/tmp/zipproblem 2>&1' );
passthru( "sqlldr USERID=scott/tiger@dbhost control=/tmp/test.ctl log=/tmp/test.log >>/tmp/sqlldrproblem 2>&1" );

Comment: In php passthru(),not only sqlldr but other command also output same result.e.g.  
php script (brwoser request):
passthru("which sqlldr");=>
output: sh which:command not found.

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.6 ()
Server built:   Mar  6 2015 15:36:38